# Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance hasMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have the two following model `Page.php` and PageCategory.php` with the following relationship:
**Page.php**

```
public function category() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\PageCategory','category_id', 'id');
}
```

**PageCategory.php**

```
public function page() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Page','id');
}
```

Below is the db table structure for above models:

*Pages*

`id | title | content | category_id`

*page_categories*

`id | name`

I'm trying to print all categories name as main menu items  and page name belonging to their category as child menu items in navbar. With the following code in controller:

`$pcategories = PageCategory::all();`

In view:

```
@foreach($pcategories as $category)
<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
     <a href="#">{{ $category->page->title }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
@endforeach
```

With the above code I'm encountering error message **Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance** I would be very thankful if anyone could point our the mistake that I've done.

Answer (score 1):

A collection can contain more than one record - by doing `$category->page` you are getting a collection of pages.

You should be looping over the collection, like so;

```
@foreach($pcategories as $category)
<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <ul>
    @foreach($category->page as $page)
    <li>
     <a href="#">{{ $page->title }}</a>
    </li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the documentation and found the same.